# How to create a customized file descriptor on linux

Tags: c, linux, file, file-descriptor

I would like to create a file whose descriptor would have some customizable behavior. In particular, I'd like to create a file descriptor, which, when written to, would prefix every line, with name of the process and pid (and maybe time), but I can imagine it can be useful to do other things.

I don't want to alter the writing program - for one thing, I want it to work for all programs on my system, even shell/perl/etc. scripts, and it would be impractical if not impossible to change the source code of everything.

Note that pipes wouldn't do in this case, because when the writing process `fork()`s, the newly created child shares the fd and is indistinguishable from its parent by the reading end of the pipe.

There are approaches which would do, but I think they are rather clumsy:

1. Create a kernel module that will create such fds. For example, you could open some `/dev/customfd` and then instruct the module to do some transformation etc. or send data to userspace or socket etc.
2. Use LD_PRELOAD that will override the fd manipulation functions and do these kinds of things on the "special" fd.

However, both of these approaches are quite laborious, so I would like to know if there is a better way, or any infrastructure (like off-the-shelf libraries) that would help.

I'd prefer a solution which doesn't involve kernel changes, but I'm ready to accept them if necessary.

Just an idea: would FUSE be an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of options , as you mentioned using the LD_PRELOAD  wrapping the write()/read() functions is a good approach.

I recommend you to use unix ptrace(2) to caught the desired system call and pass the arguments to your own function.

Example :

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/user.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_write etc */
int main()
{   pid_t child;
    long orig_eax, eax;
    long params[3];
    int status;
    int insyscall = 0;
    child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
    }
    else {
       while(1) {
          wait(&status);
          if(WIFEXITED(status))
              break;
          orig_eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                     child, 4 * ORIG_EAX, NULL);
          if(orig_eax == SYS_write) {
             if(insyscall == 0) {
                /* Syscall entry */
                insyscall = 1;
                params[0] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                                   child, 4 * EBX,
                                   NULL);
                params[1] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                                   child, 4 * ECX,
                                   NULL);
                params[2] = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                                   child, 4 * EDX,
                                   NULL);
                printf("Write called with "
                       "%ld, %ld, %ld\n",
                       params[0], params[1],
                       params[2]);
                }
          else { /* Syscall exit */
                eax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,
                             child, 4 * EAX, NULL);
                    printf("Write returned "
                           "with %ld\n", eax);
                    insyscall = 0;
                }
            }
            ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,
                   child, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have to catch fork() too, but that should be doable. However, would this suffice performance-wise, eg. if I ptrace many processes on the system? Would this solution affect the traced program?

Comment: You can trace a fork system call too, the traced process continues without changes in the execution flow/process address space. Of course that  trace processes  implies a little bit overhead (depending on the parent process implementation).