# How to create custom file descriptors on linux besides stdout/stderr?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, stderr

I want to create a special file descriptor to co-exist along /dev/std{in,out,err}. For example, lets say /dev/fd/3 and /dev/customout are created and all programs and scripts can use it in the same way they might use stderr.

In particular, if I have the following script *demo.sh*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo hello from fd 3 aka customout >& /dev/customout

echo hello from stdout
```

Calling like this to silence customout

`./demo.sh 3>/dev/null`

Should output only stdin data (plus any stderr)

`hello from stdout`

And calling like this to silence stdin

`./demo.sh 1>/dev/null`

Should output only customout data (plus any stderr)

`hello from fd 3 aka customout`

But calling without redirection should show everything:

`./demo.sh`

Should output stdout, stderr, customout

```
hello from fd 3 aka customout
hello from stdout
```

p.s. Maybe customerr is a better name for the concept.

There is this existing question but its not exactly what I am trying to achieve:

[How to create a customized file descriptor on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461335/how-to-create-a-customized-file-descriptor-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Programs inherit the fds of their parent. If you write a shell that opens 4 fds and start a program with fork/execve then it will inherit 4 fds. See also [execve() and sharing file descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3179636/1216776)

Comment: So to accomplish this I could edit the bash source code and open fd 3 in the same way that /dev/stderr is opened? Is there another way? How are /dev/std{in,out,err} even made?

Comment: All fds are made by the open syscall.